# Error While Configure JWT For Symfony2.8

Tags: symfony

Hi I need to use JWT(Json web token) for Restfull services authentication with my symfony2.8. So I am following following guide from JWT reference site:

https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Following are my steps:

```
1: configure it in AppKarnal.php
new Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle(),

2:jenerated keys on rsp[ective place app/var/jwt

3: Configure the SSH keys path in your config.yml :

lexik_jwt_authentication:
jwt_private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/var/jwt/private.pem'   # ssh    private key path
jwt_public_key_path:  '%kernel.root_dir%/var/jwt/public.pem'    # ssh    public key path
jwt_key_pass_phrase:  'mypass'                                      # ssh key pass phrase if present
jwt_token_ttl:        86400
```

4:
Configure your parameters.yml.dist :

```
jwt_private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/private.pem' # ssh    private key path
jwt_public_key_path:  '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/public.pem'  # ssh public key path
jwt_key_pass_phrase:  ''                                         # ssh key pass phrase
```

jwt_token_ttl:        3600

5: Configure your security.yml :

```
     login:
                    pattern:  ^/api/login
                    stateless: true
                    anonymous: true
                    form_login:
                        check_path:               /api/login_check
                        success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                        failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                        require_previous_session: false

                api:
                    pattern:   ^/api
                    stateless: true
                    guard:
                        authenticators:
                            - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

            access_control:
                - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
                - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

6:   Configure your routing.yml :

```
api_login_check:
path: /api/login_check
```

But even I have followed every step properly, I am getting following error:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "lexik_jwt_authentication" (in /var/www/html/EduboldApp/eduboldportal/app/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "lexik_jwt_authentication", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine_mongodb", "fos_rest", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution" in /var/www/html/EduboldApp/eduboldportal/app/config/config.yml (which is being imported from "/var/www/html/EduboldApp/eduboldportal/app/config/config_dev.yml").
```

Please help what i am missing.

I am using symfony2.8 with ODM

thank in advance

Comment: Its not working anymore even done everything. not able to figureout the isse..

Comment: Do we require FOSUserBundle for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your AppKernel.php looks like?

Is JWT bundle registered there?

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            ...
            new Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle(),
            ...

        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            ...
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
```

I guess you have installed bundle? :)

```
composer require lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle
```

Also, I think you need to remove `jwt_` from `jwt_private_key_path`, `jwt_key_pass_phrase` and `jwt_token_ttl` in config.yml

Take a look here https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#configuration

So, your config.yml should look like this:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: '%jwt_private_key_path%'
    public_key_path:  '%jwt_public_key_path%'
    pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'
    token_ttl:        '%jwt_token_ttl%'
```

Comment: new Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle(),

Comment: according to document:
php composer.phar require "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle". I have installed this

Comment: Yes, JWT Bundle is registered in Appkarna.php

Comment: What happens if you run: `php app/console debug:container lexik`

Comment: I got the same error as above:

[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                                                          
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "jwt_private_key_path" (in /var/www/html/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/app/config/parameters.yml). Looked   
  for namespace "jwt_private_key_path", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra",

Comment: my keys are inside: app/var/jwt

Comment: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "jwt_private_key_path". it is not able to load private . public key path even it placed correct place..

Comment: Error from the original question was different?

`There is no extension able to load the configuration for "lexik_jwt_authentication"`

Comment: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "jwt_private_key_path" (in /var/www/html/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/app/config/parameters.yml). I am not able to paste here complete error.

Comment: I am not able to find out the exact issue.

Comment: I think you need to remove `jwt_` from `jwt_private_key_path`, `jwt_key_pass_phrase` and `jwt_token_ttl` in config.yml

Take a look here https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#configuration

Comment: You mean like like this:

    private_key_path: '%private_key_path%'
    public_key_path:  '%public_key_path%'
    pass_phrase:      '%key_pass_phrase%'
    token_ttl:        '%token_ttl%'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133063/discussion-between-sunil-rawat-and-matko-dipalo).

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure the SSH keys path in your config.yml as like below :

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    jwt_private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/var/jwt/private.pem'   # ssh    private key path
    jwt_public_key_path:  '%kernel.root_dir%/var/jwt/public.pem'    # ssh    public key path
    jwt_key_pass_phrase:  'mypass'                                      # ssh key pass phrase if present
    jwt_token_ttl:        86400
```

Make sure you have tab after lexik_jwt_authentication:

Comment: it is like that only. i am not able to identified what is exact issue.

Comment: lexik_jwt_authentication: 
    jwt_private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/var/jwt/private.pem'   # ssh    private key path
    jwt_public_key_path:  '%kernel.root_dir%/var/jwt/public.pem'    # ssh    public key path
    jwt_key_pass_phrase:  'mypass'                                      # ssh key pass phrase if present
    jwt_token_ttl:        86400

Comment: Do we need Configure your parameters.yml.dist :

we have also paremater.yml then what where to keep it.any idea

Comment: Try to do as per documentation. Make parameters in parameters.yml then load it to config.yml. If it works then try to put it directly to config.yml. I have used this in 5 to 6 applicatoins, working excellent. You might be forgot some configurations.

Comment: paremeter.yml:

jwt_private_key_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/private.pem' # ssh private key path
jwt_public_key_path:  '%kernel.root_dir%/../var/jwt/public.pem'  # ssh public key path
jwt_key_pass_phrase:  ''                                         # ssh key pass phrase
jwt_token_ttl:        3600

Comment: This is config.yml:

lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: '%jwt_private_key_path%'
    public_key_path:  '%jwt_public_key_path%'
    pass_phrase:      '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'
    token_ttl:        '%jwt_token_ttl%'

Comment: Last 3-4 hour I am trying it but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make 4 spaces on *jwt keys on parameters.yml to resolve it. Remember, yml files is ident oriented.